# Elasticsearch python client connection timed out

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have the following error:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionTimeout: Connection timeout caused by:
ConnectionTimeout(Connection timeout caused by: 
ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=9.999005171936005)))
```

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import os
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('ELASTIC_PASSWORD')
client = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200', basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD), max_retries=3, retry_on_timeout=True)
doc = {
    'text': 'Interesting content',
}
client.ping() # returns True!!
# the program reports error
client.indices.create(index="test-index", timeout="30s")
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. increasing timeout
2. add localhost to config/elasticsearch.yml
3. use the unauthenticated version, i.e.:

```
client = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
```

4. use https (would produce connection error)

Also, note that I have been able to create the index once when I first installed Elasticsearch python client. It failed the second and third time I ran the script. Another behavior I observed was that http://localhost:9200 is always up even if I closed the program...

Installation:

1. Elasticsearch - I wget and un-tar it
2. python client: python -m pip install elasticsearch

Comment: can you try `https` ?

Comment: @MusabDogan Thanks for your reply! I tried https and it did not work.

Comment: This can be a bug. Please check this out: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/frequent-timeout-when-using-elasticsearch-py-8-1-0/300831    They also created a bug ticket and closed it.  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1947

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer: I did not work it through with local Elasticsearch client, but cloud client seems to work fine for me:

```
client = Elasticsearch(cloud_id="YOUR_CLOUD_ID", api_key="YOUR_API_KEY")
```